# Google App Engine Java: how to remove unused indexes?

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore

If I found information about removing unused indexes, like in [Uploading and Managing a Python App / Deleting Unused Indexes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Deleting_Unused_Indexes), it was only for the Python environment...

Any way to tag an index in the **[~project]/war/WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml** file?

Answer (score 5):

Since version 1.4.2 the Java SDK supports the vacuum_indexes action.
Run this command to delete unused indices:

```
./<appengine-java-sdk-path>/bin/appcfg.sh vacuum_indexes <myapp-path>/war
```

On Windows with the Eclipse SDK it's something like:

```
<eclipse-path>\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.4.3.v201103311225\appengine-java-sdk-1.4.3\bin\appcfg.cmd vacuum_indexes <myapp-path>\war
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way you currently can remove an index is using the Python SDK as described [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/c8a7888438efeb9/cdbaeb27befcfd75).

The missing `vacuum_indexes` functionality from the Java SDK is logged as a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1893), but not yet fixed.

Comment: Tom, thanks for the bug reference. With my Agile development methodology, I've a bunch of indexes that are not used anymore and it's going to become urgent to clean them up! I hope the fix will provided in a near future ;)