# Google Datastore: Error while deleting unused indexes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an application running on AppEngine and I was previously using a composed index on one of my kinds "Company" currently with about 10M entities. As I have seen in another questions we are supposed remove the index from index.yaml and use [appcfg.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128739/google-app-engine-java-how-to-remove-unused-indexes) to update the list of indexes.

Currently my indexes look like this:
[image]

And my index.yaml looks like this:

```
indexes:
- kind: Company
  properties:
  - name: dissolved
  - name: dissolution_date
```

But when I execute

```
x@y:~/webapp$ appcfg.py vacuum_indexes .
12:32 PM Host: appengine.google.com
12:32 PM Fetching index definitions diff.
Error 400: --- begin server output ---


Client Error (400)

The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.
--- end server output ---
```

Is there an error in my approach? Or has this method been deprecated and I should be using the gcloud command?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use appcfg anymore. Try using `gcloud datastore cleanup-indexes index.yaml`